# Having trouble with IF user_signed in using Devise authentication on RAILS

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm working on implementing devise user authentication on my Rails website. Everything works. My views, models, urls, etc. are all set up. Users can register, log in, log out.

The issue I'm having is with this bit of code: Even when I'm logged in, it is still displaying "Log In" as an option on the header as well as "Signup". What syntax or code can I use to make these two SPECIFIC items dissapear when the user has authenticated. The code below is in my _header.html.erb

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li> 
  <li><%= link_to "Signup", new_user_registration_path %></li>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
    <% else %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
<% else %>
<li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li> 
<li><%= link_to "Signup", new_user_registration_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

You just need to write `"Login"` and `"Signup"` in the `else` part.

Comment: This does not work. It places a second login on the header and does not achieve what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is good, just you need include login/signup in the else block so that it will not render if user signed in.

```
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
  <% else %>
    <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li> 
    <li><%= link_to "Signup", new_user_registration_path %></li>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, This part of code is fine. Have you restarted your server? Have you checked if you rendering correct partial?

Comment: You still not changed the else block in the screenshot you sent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the EXACT CODE we use:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to " ", destroy_user_session_path, class: "ion-close", id: "logout", title: "Log Out", data: { placement: "bottom", confirm: "Really Logout?" }, method: :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "", new_user_session_path, class: "ion-locked login", title: "Login / Register", data: { placement: "bottom" }, rel: "modal" %>
<% end %>
```

It's not copy/paste unfortunately (we have some other stuff we use), but it should show you how it should work.

---

In terms of your error, there is a bunch of stuff I'd recommend:

**1. Output**

Just output `<%= user_signed_in? %>` in your view.

This will show you whether it's `true`/`false` -- allowing you to determine why your conditional logic may not be working.

I personally think your sessions aren't being set; this will show it.

-

**2. Restart**

Second thing is to restart your server.

You may have some session conflicts, or another set of issues preventing the app from saving your authenticated status.

-

**3. Sessions**

Finally, there *may* be an issue with your sessions.

I don't know the specifics of this, but having `user_signed_in?` as different to what you're seeing from logging in etc suggests either multiple sessions being set, or none at all.

Either way, you may want to delete all your browser cache data (I can update with instructions on how to do this if required) to reset the sessions as you need.

Comment: Hey Rich, really appreciate you taking the time to write something so comprehensive, I will try this out and revert back.

Comment: Hey Rich, I am not using HAML. Is their a way to code this as normal.